# Redirect everyone except my ip index.php

Tags: php

i am running a website and my website root directory have .htaccess and index.php, now i want to redirect all user's/traffic to "Under-Construction.php" page except my ip address.
i.e

www.example.com   redirect to  "www.example.com/under-construction/under-construction.php"
except my ip address.

1. How can do this with .htaccess.
2. How can do this with index.php.
   example: if $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is 123.123.123 redirect index.php else redirect "www.example.com/under-construction/under-construction.php"

Regards.

Comment: make sure your ip is unique.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this with php. Put the code at the top of `index.php`.

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '123.123.123.123')))
{
  header('Location: http://www.example.com/under-construction/under-construction.php');
  exit;
}
```

Comment: where to add my ip? ('127.0.0.1', '123.123.123.123')?

Comment: oh the first ip go for internet information service! what is this i want to know why you put 127.0.0.1 ? what is this function?

Comment: @user1790627 `127.0.0.1` is the localhost ip, if you don't want it, you could remove it.

Comment: This doesnt prevent from bypassing the bootstrap. The easier method is htaccess.

Comment: @xdazz i don't know whats wrong but this method is not working everyone including my ip is redirecting to under-construction page.

Comment: @itachi could you please share some htaccess method? i have already htaccess file in my root directory.

Comment: This method should work. Just enter your ip in the array. As for htaccess method, naka chandra already gave one.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on my server:

```
    <?php
       // echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
       // For proof of concept
        if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "123.123.123.123") {
            header( 'Location: http://www.google.com/' ) ;
        }
    ?>
```

(Obviously that's not my ip ;)

Just as a side note, this may not be the best way to filter incoming clients, especially if you don't have a static ip address that you'll be requesting from. Perhaps set a cookie on your machine that tells the site who you are? Or add a $_GET parameter i.e. if $_GET['dev'] == true then redirect.

Comment: Won't work since you echo something before setting the headers. Remove the echo statement. Also OP wants to have a whitelist, not a blacklist. So you'll have to do if remote address is NOT this, then redirect.

Comment: This is just a proof of concept -- just showing that $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] returns a string :)

Comment: because you "commented" line 2. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this `.htaccess` code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$    # replace 127.0.0.1 with your IP address
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/under-construction/under-construction.php
</IfModule>
```

**Note:** Replace `127.0.0.1` with your IP address